# Vertically align icon in middle when text falls to two lines

Tags: css

I have an icon that I am vertically aligning in middle of a container using flexbox.... it looks like this

[image: ![enter image description here]

but when moving over to a small screen, when the text falls to two lines, the image is not vertically aligned where I want it to be:

[image]

I want it to be vertically aligned in the middle to the last line of text only, not vertically aligned in the middle of both lines of text. This is the result I want, with the info icon being inline with "here" and in the middle:

[image]

How can I go about achieving this?

```css
.card-heading {
  padding: 30px 20px 10px;
  display:flex;
  font-size:50px;
}

button {
  background:none;
  border:none;
 align-items: center;
}

button img {
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="card-heading"><span>CONTENT IN HERE </span><button class="card-more-imfo" type="button"><img alt="info" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/info-circle-outline.png"></button></h2>
```

Comment: simply remove display:flex

Comment: that doesn't keep it vertically aligned in the middle

Comment: use `vertical-align: Xpx;` and adjust the X like you want

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your element structure as below. You need to position your button relative to the latest parent span element which is `<span>HERE</span>` with help of `position: absolute`.

```css
.card-heading {
  /*padding: 30px 20px 10px; removing extra padding to accommodate both versions in single screen and one not need to scroll*/
  display:flex;
  font-size:50px;
}

span{
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  align-items: center;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}

button img {
  height:30px;
}

.demo-2{
  max-width: 200px; /*experiment purpose */
}
```

```html
<h2 class="card-heading">
  <span>CONTENT IN 
    <span>HERE
    <button class="card-more-imfo" type="button">
      <img alt="info" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/info-circle-outline.png">
    </button>
    </span>
  </span>
</h2>

<h2 class="card-heading demo-2">
  <span>CONTENT IN 
    <span>HERE
    <button class="card-more-imfo" type="button">
      <img alt="info" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/info-circle-outline.png">
    </button>
    </span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

Comment: the content in the span is dynamic so I cant manually add the bottom text in a another span, sometimes it falls to two lines and sometimes it doesn't ... so a solution that accommodates both is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to make some changes on your HTML tags, instead of using h2 as the parent element I decided to use a div instead and place h2 and img tags inside.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jl3r.png

```
    <div class="card-heading">
        <h2> CONTENT IN HERE </h2> <img alt="info" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/info-circle-outline.png">
    </div>
```

I had to use media queries rules and change your positioning on the icon, changing it to **absolute** and then added **padding-top**.

````
            .card-heading {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                height: auto;
                width: 100%;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            button {
                background: none;
                border: none;
            }

            img {
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 21px;
                padding-top: 55px;
            }
        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .card-heading {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                height: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            button {
                background: none;
                border: none;
            }

            img {
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                position: relative;
                padding: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: this still displays the icon all the way to the right instead of right next to "HERE"

Comment: When you shrink down your browser with just the mouse and not using a real mobile screen, you won't actually get to see the "real thing". I tested using Firefox and went into "mobile screen view" CMD + SHIFT + M

Comment: okay.... this code also always assumes that the text is going to dropdown to another line on mobile.... the content is dynamic so sometimes it doesn't drop down to two lines, which means in this case, the icon is no longer vertically aligned in the middle... it displays too low when the content is just one line

Answer (score -1):

you can either both the class of the image and of the text float to left to have them aligned as you need... i.e. in .card-heading and whichever is the class of the info image. just write `float:left;`

Comment: that doesn't keep the icon vertically aligned in the middle of the text

Comment: float did it for me to position the image next to the content